# tex4ebook and package verse, problem with space between verses

Tags: verse, tex4ebook

The following MWE tells the problem:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{stix2}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{verse}
\usepackage{tex4ebook}


\begin{document}

\begin{verse}
    Some first verse \\
    some second line
    
    This second verse\\
    lacks a space between
    
    first, second and third verse\\
    in the epub via tex4ebook
    
    when viewed both with\\
    ADE and Calibre
\end{verse}

\end{document}
```

How could this be resolved? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by a missing paragraph tag at the beginning of each stanza. It can be fixed using the following configuration file:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}

\catcode`\:=11
\Configure{verseline}
   {\ifvmode \IgnorePar\fi \EndP \end:verseln
    \HCode{<div class="verseline">}\def\end:verseln{\HCode{</div>}}\par\ShowPar}
   {\ifvmode \IgnorePar\fi \EndP \end:verseln
    \HCode{<div class="skip-verseline">}%
    \def\end:verseln{\HCode{</div>}}\par\ShowPar}
\catcode`\:=12
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

I will also update TeX4ht sources, so the configuration file should be unnecessary soon.

[image]

Comment: Thank you again, Michal. As earlier, I will wait some days to get the newest version of tex4ht (with `tlmgr update tex4ht`).